# Flex alert bubble

Tags: apache-flex

I am currently using the MX phone number validator:

```
<mx:PhoneNumberValidator id="phoneCheck" 
            source="{phoneInput}" 
            property="text" 
            allowedFormatChars=""
            required="true"
            trigger="{button}"
            triggerEvent="click"/>
```

When the validator returns an error with text (see screenshotA)[image] rather than the nifty Flash bubble (screenshotB.jpg)[image].

How do I get the bubble instead of the text? Thank you.

Comment: Show some code behind your two screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

The example shown in the link http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/validators/PhoneNumberValidator.html has the bubble on a MouseOver. Have a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want bubble instead of the text, it is only in flex 3 Form component - try use

```
<mx:Form>...
```